# Optimizing Linq: IN operator with large data

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

How to optimize this query?

```
// This will return data ranging from 1 to 500,000 records
List<string> products = GetProductsNames(); 


List<Product> actualProducts = (from p in db.Products
                               where products.Contains(p.Name)
                               select p).ToList();
```

This code takes around 30 seconds to fill `actualProducts` if I send a list of 44,000 strings, dont know what it takes for 500,000 records. :(

any way to tweak this query?

NOTE: it takes almost this much time for each call (ignoring the first slow edmx call)

Comment: Where does `GetProductsNames` get the information from?

Comment: why dont you use a join in the query?

Comment: @JonSkeet from a text file.

Comment: A text file with 500,000 products? Why aren't you using a database?

Comment: The records in text file are exported from another server, and by this we have to check how many products do we have in our local store. (Just to sync the items)

Comment: using indexof instead of contains will increase the performance slightly

Comment: @EhsanUllah no it won't; it could even stop the LINQ provider from understanding the intent

Comment: What is db.Products type?

Comment: DBSet<Products> , a table in edmx

Comment: You have two sets, the products listing from the remote system dump, and your own products database, and you want to iterate through the items in the remote system dump to see which ones you already have, by searching your dataset ~500K times, looking for name matches. Correct?

Comment: @Tim Yes, exactly the same scenario

Comment: @Tim well, the code shown doesn't "search [the] dataset ~500k times" - it does one query, with an `IN` containing 500k items. Well, actually EF might be breaking it down into a number of queries due to limits on the number of parameters - but it won't to a round-trip per element in `products`

Comment: Huh? SQL Server can only use up to 2000 parameters per query. How does this even run? Does everything execute in memory?!

Comment: @UsmanAzam You can try out my solution if that helps you

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I was just confirming that I understood what the OP needs to accomplish. If there are 500K products in the file export he gets from the remote db, the OP needs to find out the intersection with his own set. He can take each item in local set and see whether it appears in the 500K set, or he can take each item in the 500K set and see whether it appears in the local set.  Which approach to take would depend on the number of items in the local set, I think.  Also, I am not assuming he has file-create privileges on the back-end, since he did not tag the question with SQL.

Comment: @MarcGravell why is it so?

Comment: @Ehsan LINQ works by parsing an expression tree for *intent*, and then constructing SQL from that intent. At best (if it understands the intent correctly), the generated SQL from other approach will be identical. At worst, it won't recognise IndexOf - or would map it as some horrible SQL that is ridiculously sub-optimal (checking the index is not how you test for inclusion in SQL). it certainly understands Contains, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `IN` query on 500,000 records is always going to be a pathological case.

Firstly, make sure there is an index (probably non-clustered) on `Name` in the database.

Ideas (both involve dropping to ADO.NET):

- use a "table valued parameter" to pass in the values, and `INNER JOIN` to the table-valued-parameter in TSQL
- alternatively, create a table of the form `ProductQuery` with columns `QueryId` (which could be `uniqueidentifier`) and `Name`; invent a guid to represent your query (`Guid.NewGuid()`), and then use `SqlBulkCopy` to push the 500,000 pairs (the same guid on each row; different guids are different queries) into the table really quickly; then use TSQL to do an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables

Actually, these are very similar, but the first one is probably the first thing to try. Less to set up.

Comment: Will get back to you after trying this, is it possible to create a temp in code, without changing edmx at all? or is there any way to try our suggestion of temp table without modifying edmx?

Comment: @UsmanAzam to the best of my knowledge, EF will simply not *use* these approaches. So indeed - there is no requirement to edit the edmx, because editing the edmx **won't achieve anything**. This is a "drop to ADO.NET/TSQL for this particular query" thing, IMO. Keep in mind: EF is *just a tool*; you are allowed to use more than one tool. Sometimes, you need to put down the hammer and get out the screw-driver.

Comment: @UsmanAzam I wouldn't be so hasty to "accept" it until you've had chance to try it; but... it would certainly be what I did as a first thing to look at

Comment: I'm in no haste. Our another application does the same as you suggested. It looks for the parameters, if they are above 25 then it makes a temporary in db and do the rest of operation via `JOIN` query. It is in C++ using SQLAnywhere. I asked this question in the forum just because if there's any better solution available for that.

Comment: @UsmanAzam the point about table-valued-parameters is that it avoids the need to create a temporary table; if you are familiar with "table variables" then: it is basically like that, but as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Database you could try something with `Dictionary<string,string>`

If am not wrong I suspect `products.Contains(p.Name)` is expensive since it is O(n) operation. Try to change your `GetProductsNames` return type as `Dictionary<string,string>` or convert List to Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> productsDict = products.ToDictionary(x => x);
```

So you have a dictionary in hand, now rewrite the query as below

```
List<Product> actualProducts = (from p in db.Products
                           where productsDict.ContainsKey(p.Name)
                           select p).ToList();
```

This will help you to improve performance a lot(disadvantage is you allocate double memory advantage is performance). I tested with very large samples with good results. Try it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, maybe just pulling all products in memory is faster. Depends on the number and structure of the rows.

Comment: @usr I tried a query with List<string> which takes **73 seconds** to execute comes down to just **8 ms** when switched to Dictionary

Comment: @SriramSakthivel wow amazing, if this hack gives such a great performance then I will surely try it out when I get back to work (Office). Anyway Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a hashing approach using the name-column as the value that gets passed to the hashing function; then you could iterate the 500K set, subjecting each name to the hashing function, and testing for existence in your local hash file.  This would require more code than a linq approach but it might be considerably faster than repeated calls to the back-end doing inner joins.